# Neovim ERROR: 492: Not an editor command: PlugInstall

Tags: neovim

Okay, so I have installed Neovim with "sudo apt install neovim" and made directory ".config/nvim/init.nvim". While typing in "init.nvim" no words got highlited e.g. :set number. When I tried to install all of the plugins, I got the message as in the title. Can anyone help me with that?

I have looked all over the internet, tried some of the thing people suggeste but unfortunately nothing worked. Should I maybe uninstall Ubuntu as I have windows subsystem for Linux and after that install it again?

Comment: Have you checked the install guide on vim-plug [here](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#unix-linux)? Are you sure that vim-plug is installed?

Answer (score 2):

The config filename for neovim is "***init.vim***", not "***init.nvim***".

Try running :

```
:echo $MYVIMRC
```

It should printout the location and the config file name for you.

Comment: NOTE:- The command is to be run inside nvim, (i.e. in command mode). NOT in your terminal.